# So much space occupied by PyCharm and Intellij

Tags: disk-usage, intellij, pycharm

I'm trying to free up some space on my Ubuntu partition, and I've already deleted huge redundant resources such as caches and log journals. Now two directories on /snap have grabbed my attention: /snap/intellij-idea-community and /snap/pycharm-community. In each of them there are two folders with almost identical sizes, and a shortcut named "current":

[image]

[image]

As seen in the photos, these two programs take up 3.8 Gigabytes of space combined. I thought they are two different versions of the same program (because of the size similarity) but when I tried to move one of them to another directory using the `sudo mv` command, it said:

```
mv: cannot move '249' to '/home/esra/Desktop/249': Device or resource busy
```

The same happened for the two directories in /pycharm-community. Do they really belong to the same version and I'm going to screw up my IDEs if I delete one of them? If not, why can't I move any of them to somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo snap remove intellij-idea-community --revision 249
```

Comment: You are *implicitly* suggesting to remove old/not-used revisions of snap packages. Could you make it *explicit* by [edit]ing your answer? Only-code answers are deprecated.

Comment: I ran this command, and the output was: `revision 249 of snap "intellij-idea-community" is not installed`. So I tried this: `snap list --all`. This way I could see a list of all revisions snap programs and find the disabled revisions. Then I ran the command you suggested, superseding `249` with the number of the disabled revision. It worked and I freed 2 GBs of space without hampering the functionality of my IDEs. [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1162731/1132100)